# Citing one paper in consecutive paragraphs in a thesis

Tags: citations

I dedicated one subsection of my thesis to a very new topic from a 2020 paper so I had only one reference. I wrote the subsection in this way:

- paragraph 1: Introduction to the concept of X and the framework
  containing five dimensions
- paragraph 2: dimension 1
- paragraph 3: dimension 2
- paragraph 4: dimension 3
- paragraph 5: dimension 4
- paragraph 6: dimension 5
- paragraph 7: Wrap up and conclusion

Everything has been summarised (not copied) from one 2020 paper. My question is: what is the best way to cite that paper? Does it make sense to add one sentence to paragraph 1 and say that contents of this subsection is a summary of [reference]?

P.S. this new topic is not the core topic of my thesis

Comment: At first glance, this seems completely uncontroversial. What is the source of your concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open with:

> This section summarises research by A *et al.* [1].